# Weird behavior when I try to use a closure as the target of a UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton, uikit

I know I need to replace the `let` keyword with `lazy var` for accessing the property otherwise  I cannot access the 'self'.

But I found that the `button.addTarget` can build successfully as below,

Why? Normally if you try to access the property from a closure that needs to be a lazy variable, am I right?

For comparison, The `testProperty` shows red error message:

> Cannot convert value of type `(testController) -> () -> testController` to specified type `UITabBarController`

```
import UIKit

class testController: UIViewController {
    
    let actionButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.addTarget(self,  action: #selector(actionButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
    
    let testProperty: UIViewController = {
        let obj: UIViewController = self
        return obj
    }()
    
    @objc func actionButtonTapped() {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the `addTarget` signature, you will see the following:

```
open func addTarget(_ target: Any?, action: Selector, for controlEvents: UIControl.Event)
```

First parameter `target` is `Any?`, so passing `(Function)` as `target` compiles fine. It even will work but can lead to weird issues, like opening keyboard will stop the button from calling the `action`.

Comment: hi Leo, Thank you for your advice, It looks like an xcode compiler issue, I will leave this behind, Swift just feels unstable not like others.

Comment: @Jessy just run OP's code, you'll see it works even when `actionButtonTapped` isn't static

Comment: @Leo I updated my answer. Xcode 13.3 won't let it slide without a warning.

Comment: @JasonFY Why do you think this is an Xcode/compiler (those are two separate components, btw) issue? The `target` can be an `Any?`, and a closure of type `(testController) -> () -> testController` fits the bill

Answer (score 0):

You currently think that `self` refers to the instance.

But no, for an `NSObject`, it refers to partial application of [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418954-self). Actually running `ViewController.self()` before one has been instantiated, e.g. within the context of this closure, will crash your app, but `self()` used to still present itself as being available prior to Xcode 13.3.

As of now, Swift cannot cope with referring to this method without generating a warning. The warning tells you to use `ViewController.self`, which Swift can only interpret as a metatype, not a method. It doesn't understand what's going on, but at least it informs you that what you're doing is incorrect—the method is not actually the target.

Regardless of the warning, I don't know Objective-C well enough to tell you why a message sent to the method will trickle down to an instance of the related type. But don't do it.

Comment: hi, Jessy, Thank you for your reply, As I said I know what's the problem here, and I also know how to fix it in 2-3 different ways, I just wonder why the let version sometimes works fine.